# The instant an accelerating object has zero speed, is it speeding up, slowing down, or neither?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, velocity, speed

[image]

This problem is from Khan Academy. Specifically for the blue point circled in red, the answer is that at this blue point, the object is neither speeding up nor slowing down. When I think about the rule about the signs of velocity and acceleration and what this means for change in speed, this makes sense: if velocity and acceleration and have the same sign, the object is speeding up, and if velocity and acceleration have opposite signs, the object is slowing down. At the blue point, the instantaneous velocity is zero and because zero is neither positive nor negative, the object is neither speeding up nor slowing down.

However, intuitively, this doesn't make sense. At the blue point circled in red, the velocity is zero so the speed must be zero. Also, the slope of the function at this blue point is negative so acceleration is negative, meaning that velocity is decreasing every second. If velocity is decreasing every second, then right after 6 seconds, the velocity will turn negative but the speed will have increased. So at the blue point, the object, even though it has zero speed, is in the process of speeding up. Why is this thinking wrong?

Comment: Suppose you are walking, and are at the top of a hill. Are you going up or down?

Comment: When I reach the top am I at zero velocity?

Comment: And what is my acceleration at the top?

Comment: wouldn't the negative velocity mean it is going backwards? if so then it accelerated, slowed, then at 6 seconds stopped, then started accelerating backwards

Comment: You have the answer in your statement of the problem.  You define speeding up:  velocity and acceleration have the same sign (and similar for slowing down).  What is the sign of zero?   Undefined.  When $v=0$, the object does not meet the conditions for either definition, speeding up or slowing down.   It's neither.

Comment: As GaryP said:  The object is only at 0 velocity for an instant.  Basically zero time.  Acceleration and deceleration are a function of time.  So applying the same instantaneous observation at any point on that curve, you could say that the object is neither accelerating or decelerating.   Now if you assume some small time interval, then you can compare velocity at the start and end of that interval and answer the question.

Comment: It's a pendulum, it's always changing velocity (speeding up and down), It reaches zero velocity and retrocedes, the whole graphic can look like a sine wave.

Comment: I feel like this question (from Khan Academy, not the OP's) is confusing in all the wrong ways assuming the course is an introduction to physics...

Comment: This kind of question annoys me -- it all comes down to defining what you mean by "speeding up/down", which is not even very important. It's just some technicality that depends on who's making the definition, not real physics. High school physics seems to be almost entirely composed of remembering a host of technicalities like this.

Comment: I remember sitting through a week on significant figures back in high school. There are formally over 10 rules for using sig figs, 5 of which are actually useful and 5 of which are annoying edge cases that almost never actually come up. But the homework and exams end up entirely about those useless 5. Just ignore this stuff and move on.

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes! An artificial distinction with no basis in Physics which only knows  *acceleration*. After all, the specific velocity depends on the (arbitrary) observer's reference inertial system; acceleration doesn't. To understand that "slowing down" is a form of acceleration requires a mental change of every-day paradigms which are unfortunately reinforced here. Sad.

Comment: Definitely slowing down.  Of course, I'm judging this from the surface of the sun, and you haven't hit Aphelion on July 5th yet.  Seriously, this question doesn't have much point, since "speeding up" or "slowing down" are based *entirely* on your frame of reference.

Comment: @Kevin In problems like this the lab frame is assumed.  In any case, I agree that "speeding up" and "slowing down" are not valid terms in Physics.  Any instructional material that uses these terms should instantly be suspect.  Problems like this should always be framed in terms of acceleration.

Comment: I feel like I am being jerked around here...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the first point prior to the one you circled, the object is slowing down. Its velocity instantaneously is dropping and approaching the zero axis. However, at $0 \, \frac{m}{s}$, the instantaneous velocity has ceased dropping (because it has now reached zero, it can't slow down more than $0\, \frac{m}{s}$) but hasn't yet begun speeding up in the negative direction.

You may wonder, "but how can it not be speeding up or slowing down if its acceleration is not zero?" As we know, acceleration is the slope of the graph. At the circled point acceleration is non-zero because the object is *changing directions* from the positive to the negative direction, not because it is speeding up/slowing down.

Positive and negative signs here don't refer to slowing down and speeding up; they refer to two directions - the positive direction and negative direction. If this was a position vs. time graph then negative would refer to a negative position *relative to the zero position* and vice versa for positive. Positive and negative as signs are used here to give you a 1 dimensional line along which you can move in two directions with the origin being an arbitrary point we call zero.

A good physical one dimensional analogy to this question (although its velocity curve would be linear and not curved) is a ball that is dropped vertically. After impacting  the ground it is moving $0 \,\frac{m}{s}$ and has lost all its downward speed but hasn't gained any upwards speed yet *in that instant* (it's in the "in between stage of speeding up and slowing down"). The mathematical explanation for this is that the derivative of the magnitude of $v$ (which determines if the object is speeding up/slowing down) is **undefined**. At that instant acceleration (the derivative of $v$, not the magnitude of $v$) is non zero and pointing upwards, acting to *change* the ball's direction of motion.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. But Khan Academy is wrong then?

Comment: If they are saying that it's neither speeding up nor speeding down then yes, they are wrong. But perhaps you're misunderstanding the question or answer, I'm not sure because I can't see their explanation

Comment: Good point I will try to find it

Comment: Can't find it but here is a video from Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-diff-contextual-applications-new/bc-4-2/v/interpreting-speed-from-velocity-time Check out 2:27

Comment: I suppose you could grant his argument and explain that its acceleration is non-zero at that point because the object is changing directions not speeding up/down. I guess I will change my answer to agree with his actually to avoid confusion. Honestly, it's kind of semantics at that point. Saying it isn't speeding up/down but just changing directions is ambiguous in 1 dimension anyways because it happens immediately. It's not like an object moving in a circle.

Comment: He defines acceleration (the slope of the velocity graph) here https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/acceleration-tutorial/a/acceleration-article

Comment: But the acceleration is clearly negative though like you said but I do understand the argument of Sal Khan that its changing directions so its neither speeding up nor slowing down. So you and Sal are both correct, it just depends on what explanation we are using to justify an answer?

Comment: No, Sal is honestly correct & I am wrong. Think about it this way, if you could move two directions, how else would we know when an object changes directions other than when it's velocity is zero? In order to change directions in 1D you have to STOP from going one direction in one instant & begin moving the other direction. It all comes down to a matter of instantaneous time. Instantaneously, the object is changing directions at a constant speed of 0 m/s. You could accelerate just by turning in circles and not actually moving but that is easier understood in 2 dimensions, not 1

Comment: Actually I take last part back since acceleration is not simply changing the direction you are facing but changing the direction you are moving so moving is a prerequisite - in 2 dimensions. If you've learned about vectors yet, the zero vector has no direction so simply spinning in circles doesn't count as acceleration. You really can't make an analogy between 2 dimensions and this. 1 dimension is a unique case of changing directions with a constant speed of zero now that I think about it. In 2D or 3D you have to actually be moving to accelerate without speeding up/down

Comment: It all just depends on if you allow your definition of speed to include negative values, and if becoming "more negative" means "slowing down". Of course this terminology is not what is usually meant, but I suppose it isn't wrong if you are upfront about it from the beginning. 


Or you can look at it from the difference between speed (magnitude) and velocity (vector). Vectors cannot increase or decrease. Only their magnitudes can. A change in sign here really just shows a change in direction. Good answer, very subtle points being discussed here.

Comment: Thanks! Speed by definition cannot include negative values. Speed is simply the magnitude of the velocity. We can explain decreasing NEGATIVE velocity as speeding up in the negative direction - two bits of information there, its growing magnitude (speed/magnitude of velocity) & direction of movement (sign of velocity). We can use increasing NEGATIVE velocity as slowing down in the negative direction (& vice versa for the positive direction). If we allow speed to include negative numbers indicating direction then we are really just talking about velocity & speed loses its explanatory usefulness

Comment: “1 dimension is the only case where you can accelerate without moving (at a speed of zero).” This simply isn’t true. One can easily write down a velocity vector which becomes zero at some time but has no zero acceleration at that time.

Comment: "but has no zero acceleration at that time" - I'm taking this to mean it DOES have acceleration? Give me an example

Comment: The particle motion given by $\textbf{x}(t)=\cos(t^2)\,\hat{i}+\sin{t^2}\,\hat{j}$ has zero velocity but nonzero acceleration at $t=0$. Almost any example of a particle trajectory which has vanishing velocity at some point will have nonzero acceleration at that point.

Comment: That's true, I will amend my answer

Comment: I think that the key thing here is that the object's speed is not differentiable. As the absolute value of velocity (in this 1-dimensional case), the speed has a kink at the circled point. So if "speeding up" means "positive derivative of speed", "slowing down" means "negative derivative of speed", and "not changing speed" means "zero derivative of speed", then the key observation is that it's possible for none of these three things to be true.

Comment: @DanStaley I think you've identified the key here - the derivative of the object's speed is undefined at t=6. In my view, that means trying to interpret the derivative at t=6 is a meaningless exercise. It's not positive, it's not negative, it's not zero - it's simply undefined. You can argue that the object is not speeding up, but you can equally well argue that the object is not *not* speeding up. Saying the object is both speeding up and slowing down is exactly as valid as saying it's neither speeding up nor slowing down.

Comment: @Dan absolutely right. I think gettingi nto the details of the speed being undifferentiable is a bit too technical for anyone studying this level of Khan academy anyways. It may add to the confusion. Ultimately, it's a bad question to ask early physics students. The fact that this simple question has garnered so much attention from people "over qualified" to ever study kinematics on khan academy is kind of evidence of that. It's an interesting but pointless thought problem imo. It's of no use in real physics

Comment: In my view, the people focusing on the fact that the derivative is undefined are neglecting the detail that time is moving in the positive direction. Thus the answer depends on the _right derivative_, which is indeed defined and is positive.

Answer (score 38):

The tricky part of this question is that you are given a graph of *velocity* but asked a question about *speed*.

Several others have said essentially the same thing, but what really makes this clear for me is a graph of speed:

[image: y = |4 - ((x - 2) / 2) ^ 2|]

The above is the graph of $$ y = \left \lvert 4 - \left ( \frac{x - 2}{2} \right ) ^2 \right \rvert \text{,}$$ which is just the absolute value of the velocity graph in your screenshot.

This represents the fact that **speed is the absolute value of velocity**.

We understand "slowing down" to mean that the slope of the speed is negative, and "speeding up" to mean that the slope of the speed is positive. What is the slope of point $(6, 0)$ on the graph (which corresponds to your circled dot)?

This point is a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)). The notion of "slope" only exists for differentiable points, and as [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity),

> a function with a bend, cusp, or vertical tangent may be continuous, but fails to be differentiable at the location of the anomaly.

Thus *the slope of speed does not exist at this point*, and so the object is neither speeding up nor slowing down in this instant.

Comment: "Slope > 0" means speeding up, "Slope < 0" means slowing down. Since slope is undefined at the point in question, we wind up with the comparisons of "Undefined > 0" and "Undefined < 0". Your answer suggests both of these statements are false, but really they cannot be evaluated. It's like asking "is this sandwich positive, negative, or neither?". Saying an undefined value is nonpositive is like saying a sandwich is nonpositive - it's a meaningless statement because you're using qualifiers that simply don't apply. I agree "neither" is probably the correct answer, but it's a terrible question.

Comment: Rather he is saying the statements are not true. Which is correct. This is the best answer IMHO.

Comment: @NuclearWang you raise a good point. Perhaps to be more precise we define "speeding up" as "slope exists and is positive." Then, we have no issue with undefined comparison. This is similar to definitions in calculus, for example the [limit definition of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions), which requires a limit to exist and be equal to a certain value.

Comment: @Rad80 "Not true" and "false" are identical for statements with well-defined truth values. By applying the "less than" sign in a situation where it is not applicable, we have crafted a logically self-inconsistent statement that is neither true nor false. The resolution, as in the Liar Paradox, is that we *cannot meaningfully assign truth values* of true (not false) or false (not true) to the original statement

Comment: My issue with these answers based on the derivative is that the standard derivative assumes no directionality on the independent variable. But time _does_ have a direction. For this reason, it is best to consider a _one-sided derivative_ (see, for example, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability)). And in this context, there is an unambiguous answer.

Comment: @MichaelGrant In this case, the one sided derivatives do not agree (one is negative and one is positive). How do you justify choosing one over the other?

Comment: Because time evolves in the positive direction, that's why.

Comment: The fallacy here is that people are constructing the speed plot and _then_ looking at the derivative to obtain acceleration, as if that's the only way you can think about it. But in fact, in the velocity space, the acceleration is a continuous function, and we know it is nonzero at that crossing point. A speed acceleration that is right-continuous is entirely consistent with the math, _and_ with the physical reality.

Comment: There is an infinite family of speed-acceleration functions that are consistent with the cusped speed plot. They are identical of course at every instant of time except the instant where the cusp occurs. So then we have a choice to make: which of those acceleration functions should we select? I argue the right-continuous version is the one that aligns best with physical reality. Yes, I'm ignoring calculus, because calculus is in service to physics, not vice versa.

Comment: One more argument. Suppose you began observing the particle only at the instant it had zero velocity. After observing the slope of the speed curve from that point forward, it would be entirely sensible to conclude it had nonzero acceleration. What happed immediately prior to your observation is irrelevant.

Comment: As a counterpoint, imagine observing a particle for some amount of time until its speed reaches zero. In that instant, if you were to compute the change in speed of the particle, the data you would have would suggest that the particle is slowing down. At any given instant, we have no information about how the particle will behave in the future. This is because of the directionality of time. By your logic, then, shouldn't we only look at the left-sided derivative?

Comment: Why would I be more concerned about what we _observe_ about what is occurring as opposed to what actually is occurring? But to answer your question: it would not make a difference if we are measuring velocity instead of speed. Speed is an artificial function of the natural dynamic variable, velocity.

Comment: But even if, for the sake of argument, we were measuring the instantaneous change in speed, in effect taking the left-derivative we would discover that it was negative—and the actual speed itself zero. It would be reasonable to conclude that sign change in acceleration is about to occur.

Comment: I think you're also getting caught up in the velocity vs. speed issue, which is the crux of this question. Velocity is getting more negative, but at the specified point, speed is getting both more negative and more positive (or neither).

Comment: Speed cannot get more negative if it is zero. It has a nonzero change in speed, we know this, and a zero speed. There is one only way to go. It is like being at the south pole; any change takes you north.

Comment: Everyone is focusing so much on the calculus they are missing the commonsensical view of the physics. Math's job is to explain the physics not the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95018/discussion-between-jarhill0-and-michael-grant).

Answer (score 24):

I will provide a bit more formal of an answer. "Speeding up" or "slowing down" typically refers to whether the *speed* of an object is increasing or decreasing. Imagine you are in a boat speeding down a canal (so that you may only move in one dimension - the canal is very narrow). At $t=2$, you flip a switch and your engine starts running in reverse. Here there is an instant where your *acceleration* is 0 before becoming negative, and this corresponds to the maximum on your velocity-time plot. Now, your engine is running in reverse and your boat is "slowing down" in the traditional sense. This corresponds to $2<t<6$ in your plot. There comes an instant where you have killed off all of your velocity, and you start running in reverse. After you kill off your velocity, your speed begins to increase (you are "speeding up").

In math, we can explain this as follows. The speed of an object is defined as the magnitude of its velocity. In 1 dimension, this is saying

$$
s = |v|
$$
i.e. speed is the absolute value of velocity. If we are interested in whether or not you are speeding up or slowing down, we want to find $ds/dt$. This can be done using the chain rule of ordinary calculus. First, we note that:
$$
|v| \equiv \sqrt{v^2} = (v^2)^{1/2}
$$
as a definition. We take the derivative now:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d|v|}{dt} &= \frac{d(v^2)^{1/2}}{dt}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(v^2)^{-1/2}\cdot 2v\cdot \frac{dv}{dt} \\
&= \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2}}\cdot \frac{dv}{dt} \\
&=\frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2}}\cdot a
\end{align}
$$

This final expression tells us a few things. First, we recover the rule that you are familiar with: namely, that if $v$ and $a$ have the same sign, then $ds/dt$ will be positive. If they have different signs, it will be negative. However, we also note that we have a discontinuity at $v=0$, which is the situation considered here. At zero, $v/\sqrt{v^2}$ jumps from $-1$ to $1$ and the derivative $ds/dt$ does not exist - the speed is *formally undefined*. This is known as the sign function $sgn(v)$, which returns the sign of the argument. Since the derivative of the speed does not exist at $v=0$ in one dimension, we are justified in saying that we are neither speeding up or slowing down. However, the velocity is decreasing this whole time, as evidence by the constant negative acceleration.

Comment: Oh crap. You're talking about 2 seconds? Sorry. I totally flaked on that. I withdraw it all.

Comment: @dmckee No worries, just making sure I wasn't mistaken.

Comment: t=6 is the last moment at which the object is slowing down (according to the left-sided derivative), and the first moment at which it speeds up (according to the right-sided derivative). It wasn't an option as an answer, but I think "both" is as defensible an answer as "neither". The object isn't speeding up, nor slowing down, nor staying at constant speed, which are the only three possibilities - the real answer is that the change in speed at t=6 is undefined and cannot be meaningfully interpreted.

Comment: @NuclearWang Your point about the speed being undefined is a good one, and I will make it explicit. I agree that "both" should be a valid interpretation as well as "neither". Ultimately, it cannot be interpreted (though the answer given by Khan academy is at least an understandable one in this light).

Comment: @NuclearWang you're on the right track. But surely you see there is a reason to favor the right-derivative over the left when the independent variable is _physical time_, a quantity that evolves in a singular direction.

Answer (score 6):

Something doesn’t seem correct. For a curve of velocity versus time the acceleration at any point on the curve is the derivative of the function, that is, the instantaneous slope of the curve at the point.

At the circled point the slope is negative and not zero, indicating negative acceleration. So while the velocity at the circled point is zero it is still changing, in this case changing direction.

The slope of the curve corresponding to t=2 seconds, on the other hand, appears to be zero. That’s where the acceleration is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you are agreeing with what Andrew said basically?

Comment: You are emphasizing how the answer of "neither speeding up nor slowing down" only applies to t=2 seconds for the graph above

Comment: @user532874 Regarding your first comment, I agree with what Andrew said. We both posted answers at nearly the same time and I did not see his answer when I posted mine. My answer differs mainly in that I emphasize  acceleration is the derivative of the velocity vs time function (slope of the curve) and that clearly the slope is not zero when the velocity is zero, therefore the acceleration is not zero.

Comment: @user532874 Regarding your second comment, the slope of the curve at t=2 s is zero and, yes, that means it is "neither speeding up nor slowing down". To the left of that point the slope is positive and the object was speeding up (accelerating). To the right of the point the slope becomes negative and the object is slowing down (decelerating). At t=2 sec it is neither speeding up nor slowing down. If you have represented the Khan Academy analysis correctly, then it appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Actually, Andrew realized Khan Academy is right because their justification is that the object is changing directions at the blue point circled in red so it is not speeding up and it is not slowing down.

Comment: @user532874 I suppose so but I thought Khan Academy was implying zero acceleration, which would not be correct. I like a lot of Khan Academy's stuff, but sometimes I think clarity is not one of their stronger points.

Comment: The mixing of technical language and casual language in kinematics is one of the most fruitful sources of trick questions in all of physics. Unfortunately giving trick questions to students who haven't had time to even start getting the subject organized in their heads is a bad, *bad* idea. (And, students often generate such questions for themselves.) But instructors can at least (a) be clear about the distinction between casual and technical language, (b) clearly identify trick questions as such, and (c) not grade introductory students on them

Answer (score 3):

**Speed** is the magnitude of the velocity and hence always a positive quantity.

If the terms “speeding up” and “slowing down” refer to the speed then at the time indicated on the graph the speed is zero and having reached a minimum (zero) the speed would have been increasing in the future.
The problem is that prior to that time the speed was deceasing to eventually reach zero and that means that a graph of speed against time is discontinuous at the time in question ie the gradient of the graph is not defined at that time.
So perhaps that is why the response "neither" was given as being correct?

The rate of change of **velocity** (acceleration), the gradient of the velocity against time graph which is well defined, is negative and so at that time the rate of change of velocity (acceleration) is negative.
What was happening was that the direction of motion of the body changed at that time from moving in the positive direction to moving in the negative direction.
So one could say that the component of velocity, in the direction which was chosen to be positive, changed from being positive to being negative.
The label on the graph "velocity" is an abbreviation for "component of velocity in a chosen direction".

If one looked at the speedometer (a devise which measures speed) just before the 
that the speed was decreasing and just after that time the speed was increasing but **at the instant of time in question** which one of the two options do you choose?

Answer (score 2):

The object is **neither** speeding up nor slowing down, or **both** speeding up and slowing down. The graph you show plots velocity vs time, which can be converted to speed by taking the absolute value. The rate of change in speed is the derivative of the speed function. On the graph of speed, we can see a discontinuous corner at t=6 where the graph touches the x-axis and leaves again. The derivative at this point is undefined, making its interpretation rather nebulous - it's not negative, it's not non-negative, it's not positive, it's not non-positive, it's not zero, it's simply undefined.

We can argue that this undefined derivative isn't positive (i.e. speeding up), nor is it negative (i.e. slowing down), so the object is neither speeding up nor slowing down. But we can equally well argue that the derivative is not negative and not zero (i.e. speeding up) and that the derivative is not positive and not zero (i.e. slowing down), so the object is both speeding up and slowing down.

But really, the rate change of the object's speed is undefined at t=6. We cannot say anything meaningful about the rate of change in the object's speed at t=6, as we literally cannot define it. Even the reasoning I use the previous paragraph is rather specious - there isn't really any basis to claim that an undefined quantity is not positive or non-zero. Undefined > 0 and Undefined < 0 aren't false or true statements, they simply cannot be evaluated. It's like asking if a sandwich is positive or negative - the term just doesn't apply.

Comment: Yep. And in most cases, we just shouldn't talk about "is speeding up" or "is slowing down", and just say "is accelerating in this direction". Only friction works on speed (as in brakes), all other forces work on velocity (more precisely: momentum).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion khan academy is majorly correct . You may think that the acceleration at $$v=0$$ 
 that is the derivative at the point where the velocity is zero is negative then it must be slowing down.but the term speeding up or speeding down means that if the modulus of velocity is increasing or decreasing.

Think physically
 this graph shows the body speeding down in a direction then stopping and then reversing it's direction to speed up in an opposite direction.
 so before the moment it stops it speeds down.
 after the moment it stops it speeds up
 and at the moment it stops it neither speeds up or speeds down.
That is $$d/dy{|v|}=0$$

Edit:
Thanks to dmckee to suggest that actually  the graph of |v| would have kink at v=0
And thus the graph is non differentiable at 0
So I'd want to add
I didn't thought in mathematical way but physical way and in any real physical system kinks in graph or undefined limits are not possible

[various cases](https://photos.app.goo.gl/NXK1QxBFSGz3Raa99)

.so yeah I should not use the word absolutely .I think the question was made to think about the change in velocity in more physical way not mathematical one . But we should suggest khan to modify the graph such that there would not be any kinks in |v|

Comment: The derivative of speed is not zero but *undefined* at that $t=6$ (the left and right limits are different). That does make Khan's answer defensible, but it makes the question marginal in the first place.

Comment: @dmckee the curve  smooth at $t = 6$?

Comment: $v(t)$ is smooth at $t = 6$, but $|v(t)|$ is not.

Comment: Well dmckee is certainly correct and honestly I didn't thought in mathematical way but physical way and in any real physical system kinks in graph or undefined limits are not possible.so yeah I should not use the word absolutely .I think the question was made to think about the change in velocity in more physical way not mathematical one . But we should suggest khan to modify the graph such that there would not be any kinks in |v|

Comment: Kinks are possible in the speed graph

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the kink; the problem is people's interpretation of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the chart of the movement of an airplane which transitions into  "beta" or thrust reverse at time 2, and steadily increases thrust reverse from then onward. The aircraft slows to a stop, but does not deselect thrust reverse but continues advancing it. So the instant it stops, it heels back and starts rolling backwards down the runway.

At speed 0, the circled point, the reverse thrust levers have not been zeroed and continue to be advanced steadily.

That's pretty clear.  *acceleration* is a linear function (straight line) here, crossed zero at time 2, and it’s definitely nonzero at time 6.

The only thing that makes time 6 interesting is this is when velocity crosses the zero line.   That, plus $6, will get you a small coffee at Starbucks, but it has no bearing on acceleration.  At time 6/velocity 0, it is definitely accelerating.

The plane is stopped, the thrust reversers are howling, and the tower is wondering what the pilot intends. (Missed exit?)   So is velocity increasing at the circled instant? It is zero and in the next instant his velocity will be more, so yes.  Sounds like increasing to me.

No, you say? Then the question of "speed increasing" boils down to semantics.  It seems like a trick/dodge question.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming one dimensional motion so that when the speed is $+ve$ it is moving away from some fixed point and when it is $-ve$ it is moving in the opposite direction, back towards the fixed point.

Between $t = 0 s$ and $t = 2 s$ the slope of speed versus time is $+ve$ so that the particle is increasing its speed. At $t= 2 s$ the speed is $+ 4 m/s$ but it's acceleration is zero. Its speed is neither increasing or decreasing at this time.

For $t > 2 s$ the slope is negative so that the speed of the body is decreasing. It comes to a momentarily stop at $t = 6 s$ but its velocity appears to become more $-ve$ as time increases. Remember, velocity is "speed + direction" so that it's actual speed (magnitude of velocity) is getting larger.